# Enlarge plots and customize plot legends

Tags: plotting, manipulate, legending

1. I am trying to enlarge the plots. They are too small. In particular, I would like the intersection of the curves (sav-curves and depr-curves) to be more evident. Where and how do I implement this?
2. I want to change the plot legends to have custom labels. As you can see in the image below, my code produces inappropriate labels.

Here is my code:

```
prodA[k_, a_] := a*k^0.5;
prodB[k_, b_, c_] := b*k^(0.5) - c;
depr[k_, d_] := d*k;
savA[k_, s_, a_] := s*prodA[k, a];
savB[k_, s_, b_, c_] := s*prodB[k, b, c];
depr[k_, d_] := d*k;
Manipulate[
 If[default, {s = .3, δ = .02, a = 1, range = 30, 
   default = False}, Null];
 Column[{
   Plot[{ConditionalExpression[prodA[k, a], 0 <= k < (c/(b - a))^2], 
     ConditionalExpression[prodB[k, b, c], (c/(b - a))^2 <= k],
        depr[k, d],
        ConditionalExpression[savA[k, s, a], 0 <= k < (c/(b - a))^2], 
     ConditionalExpression[savB[k, s, b, c], (c/(b - a))^2 <= k]},
        {k, 0, range}, 
    PlotStyle -> {LightRed, LightBlue, Orange, Red, Blue}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-70, range}, {-9.9, 37}}, 
    PlotLegends -> "Expressions"],
   Plot[{ConditionalExpression[savA[k, s, a]/k, 
      0 <= k < (c/(b - a))^2], 
     ConditionalExpression[savB[k, s, b, c]/k, (c/(b - a))^2 <= k],
      depr[k, d]/k}, {k, 0, range}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Orange}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-70, range}, {-9.9, 37}}, 
    PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]}],
 {{s, .3, "savings rate γ"}, .05, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{d, .5, "depreciation rate δ"}, .015, 2, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{a, 4, "technology A"}, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 5, "technology B"}, 5, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, 4, "setup cost c"}, 4, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{range, 150, "plot range"}, 30, 300, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Button["reset", {s = .3, d = .5, a = 4.9, b = 5, c = 4, range = 150, 
    default = False} &]]
```

[image]

Comment: Manuel, welcome to mma.se. Please remember, when you see good questions and answers, to vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), and to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem by clicking the [checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For enlarging the plots, use the option `ImageSize` within the `Plot` command and specify your own entries for `PlotLengeds` in a list.

```
prodA[k_, a_] := a*k^0.5;
prodB[k_, b_, c_] := b*k^(0.5) - c;
depr[k_, d_] := d*k;
savA[k_, s_, a_] := s*prodA[k, a];
savB[k_, s_, b_, c_] := s*prodB[k, b, c];
depr[k_, d_] := d*k;
Manipulate[
 If[default, {s = .3, \[Delta] = .02, a = 1, range = 30, 
   default = False}, Null];
 Column[{
   Plot[{
     ConditionalExpression[prodA[k, a], 0 <= k < (c/(b - a))^2], 
     ConditionalExpression[prodB[k, b, c], (c/(b - a))^2 <= k], 
     depr[k, d], 
     ConditionalExpression[savA[k, s, a], 0 <= k < (c/(b - a))^2], 
     ConditionalExpression[savB[k, s, b, c], (c/(b - a))^2 <= k]}, {k,
      0, range}, PlotStyle -> {LightRed, LightBlue, Orange, Red, Blue},
    PlotRange -> {{-70, range}, {-9.9, 37}},
    PlotLegends -> {"Döpp", "Döpp", "Döpp", "dö", "dö"},
    ImageSize -> 360
    ],
   Plot[{
     ConditionalExpression[savA[k, s, a]/k, 0 <= k < (c/(b - a))^2], 
     ConditionalExpression[savB[k, s, b, c]/k, (c/(b - a))^2 <= k], 
     depr[k, d]/k}, {k, 0, range}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Orange},
    PlotRange -> {{-70, range}, {-9.9, 37}},
    PlotLegends -> {"döpp", "döpp", "döpp!"},
    ImageSize -> 360
    ]}],
 {{s, .3, "savings rate \[Gamma]"}, .05, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{d, .5, "depreciation rate \[Delta]"}, .015, 2, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a, 4, "technology A"}, 1, 5, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 5, "technology B"}, 5, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, 4, "setup cost c"}, 4, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{range, 150, "plot range"}, 30, 300, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Button["reset", {s = .3, d = .5, a = 4.9, b = 5, c = 4, range = 150, 
    default = False} &]
 ]
```

[image]